# Python selenium: how to control "run flash allow/block"?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I'd like to click "Allow" in Python selenium.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can try: `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()`

Comment: it would be proper to give some explanation for your answer to be considered an answer

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: This doesn't work because that pop up is not kind of alert... it raises errors like this: no alert window exists